# Slow rendering of ListView in expandable RecyclerView

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-recyclerview

I've been having a performance problem with an application I'm developing.
So the structure of the app is basically a single Activity with three Fragments.

One of the Fragments is a RecyclerView in which each row has a ListView that is created (as in creating and setting the adapter) in the onBindViewHolder method of the Adapter.

For the ListView Adapter I'm using a simple ArrayAdapter with an array of Strings, and a custom layout that's just a CheckedTextView.

This ListViews start with visibility gone and are shown when the row is clicked.

Now, the problem I'm having is that the first time I click a row to "expand" this sub-list (the ListView) it freezes for a couple of seconds and skips 100-140 frames. Every time the ListView is collapsed or expanded after that works fine and doesn't skip frames. This happens on every individual row.

So what I was thinking is that the ListView isn't inflated (or binded?) until is needed for the first time (visibility == true) and that is generating performance problems.

The other thing that I've noticed, via the Profiler in Android Studio, is that there is more CPU usage, and for longer time, when expanding the ListView than when rendering the RecyclewView for the first time, which is weird concidering the RecyclerView Adapter has much more complex logic and more items than the ListView with the default ArrayAdapter and only 3 items.

Here is an image for reference:

[image: Image of the Android Studio Profiler]

- After the application starts, the first touch event (Purple circle at
  the top) is the button that brings the RecyclerView fragment into
  view, with a 50% CPU usage for around 1 second.
- The second touch
  event is when a row in the RecyclerView is clicked for the first
  time, with a 50% CPU usage for around 3 seconds (Three times as
  much!).
- The next four touch events are when the same row is clicked
  again, collapsing and expanding it, with each using at most 10% CPU.
- The last touch event is, again, clicking a different row for the
  first time.

This is the layout of the RecyclerView Row:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_rv_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/rv_item_padding">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/row_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="22sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title"
            android:text="Subtitle"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/row_extended"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row_main"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:animationCache="false"
        android:scrollingCache="false">

    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the ListView child layout:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft" />
```

and this is the Fragment's layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".fragments.RVFragment"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_done"
            style="@style/MyApp.Buttons.Basic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_nav_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bottom_nav_height"
            android:text="@string/completed"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I've been scratching my head about this for some time.

UPDATE:
    I might try and use thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view and see how it goes, it may be something wrong with my implementation.

LAST UPDATE:
    So, the problem seems to have fixed itself. I wish I could explain better but all I did was moving a couple of folders around and now it works perfect.